# dictionary with counter dictionary (multiple keys) as a 2 column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I have a dictionary of bigrams, which was created as

```
self.bigram_counts = defaultdict(lambda: Counter())
```

2 sample rows from self.bigram_counts:

```
 [(None, Counter({'de': 1})),
 ('de', Counter({'la': 7839,filtradojardin': 1,'cantera': 236})))]
```

Trying to load it into a dataframe as follows seems inefficient:

```
bigrams2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list((vocab.bigram_counts.keys(), 
                                       vocab.bigram_counts.values().keys()), 
                                       vocab.bigram_counts.values().values()))
```

I would like 2 columns out of this dataframe, one with the full bigram, and one with the count. What's the best way of calling pd.DataFrame in this case?

Previously, I used:

```
bigrams = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list(vocab.bigram_counts.items()))
bigrams.columns = [['word(s)', 'count(s)']]
bigrams.head()
```

Which works but provides a counter object for the count column. I don't think .melt() is right here, but maybe something similar can be used?

Desired output:

```
     0    1
0    None, de            1
1    de, la           7839
2    de, filtradojardin  1
3    de, cantera       236
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example? That will surely allow us to help you more efficiently.

Comment: added some now, hope this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
flat_bigram_counts = (
    (word1, word2, count)
    for word1, counter in bigram_counts
    for word2, count in counter.items()
)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(flat_bigram_counts)
```

My machine outputs the following for the two rows in your example:

```
      0               1     2
0  None              de     1
1    de              la  7839
2    de  filtradojardin     1
3    de         cantera   236
```

Comment: @FredericBastiat not 100% sure this is what you wanted; if not, please add the expected output for the two example rows in your question to clarify

Comment: Very close. I updated my question with desired output. Thank you

Comment: I put ((word1, word2), count) in the second line of your code and it seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: ack I'm getting ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. when feeding to pca.fit(flat_bigram_counts). I know I need to flatten these tuples but I'm getting tripped up. please help.

Comment: (I made a small edit to my answer, adding `df`.) In general, DataFrames "don't like" having tuples or lists as elements (the only sequence they're really okay with is strings). So my gut tells me to stick with the `(word1, word2, count)` layout, make the `df` variable as in my edit, and use something like `pca.fit(df)`. (Maybe each word column is a feature? Sorry, I don't know much about data sci.)